# Sending variable to a C# inside Javascript code

Tags: c#, javascript, variables

Javascript Code:

```
function jsfunction ()
{
var sayi = 9999;
alert('<%= cfunction("'+sayi+'")%>');
}
```

C# Code:

```
public string cfunction(string gelen)
{
 return gelen;
}
```

Normally,There is should be `9999` value which is send to C# code from javascript code,but,this value returning as `'+sayi+'`.
 Also,that's gives me  alert 9999.What am I wrong?

Comment: You are misunderstanding several things, but first of all, you code should not even compile.  You are declaring the `sayi` variable in javascript, and consuming it in C# (between the `<%=` and `%>`).  That is not possible, so where is `sayi` declared such that the **C#** code can see it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# (server-side) can generate markup for client side, client side can't call back up to server-side without some kind of [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) type web request.

To do what you're looking for you can create a C# [webmethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

```
[WebMethod()]
public static string cfunction(string gelen)
{
    return gelen;
}
```

And consume the webmethod with a client-side [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method (You'll need the jQuery library script if you don't have it already)

```
function jsfunction() {
    var sayi = 9999;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "YOUR-ASPX-PAGE.aspx/cfunction",
        data: "{gelen:'" + sayi + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            alert(msg.d);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4):

By the time JavaScript runs, the C# code has already been executed. Learn you page life cycle.

If you want to call a serverside function to get data, you need to learn about Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can use scriptmethod attribute to invoke server side method from your javascript code. But you must understand the mechanism behind it so that u can debug and modify accordingly.

http://www.chadscharf.com/index.php/2009/11/creating-a-page-method-scriptmethod-within-an-ascx-user-control-using-ajax-json-base-classes-and-reflection/